# Getting the client IP in a Jersey Netty container

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, netty

I'm writing a JAX-RS REST API in a Jersey Netty container. I need to get the client IP address in a resource that I am working on. Most people specify to add `@Context HttpServletRequest` to get it, however this is either null or throws a `ClassNotFoundException` as I don't have a servlet. I would find it odd if this use-case isn't supported, does anyone know how to get hold of the client IP?